# Testing an expression for missing-ness

Tags: r, metaprogramming

I am doing some metaprogramming where I do depth-first traversal over a function body to implement partial-evaluation. Here, I am running into a problem when I encounter local variables. With those, I have to process `pairlist` objects and I want to process these depth-first. I am annotating expressions with attributes to propagate information.

A dummy-example of what I am doing could look like this:

```
dummy_expr_processing <- function(expr) {
    attr(expr, "foo") <- "bar"
    expr
}
dummy_pairlist_processing <- function(expr) {
    for (i in seq_along(expr))
        expr[[i]] <- dummy_expr_processing(expr[[i]])
}
```

which works fine for

```
f <- quote(function(x = 42, y = x) x + y)
dummy_pairlist_processing(f[[2]])
```

It breaks, however, for

```
f <- quote(function(x, y = x) x + y)
dummy_pairlist_processing(f[[2]])
```

because here, the `expr` is missing when I process `x` in the pair-list. I get the error

```
Error in dummy_expr_processing(expr[[i]]) : 
  argument "expr" is missing, with no default
Called from: dummy_expr_processing(expr[[i]])
```

I can try to get explicit about the argument

```
dummy_pairlist_processing <- function(expr) {
    for (i in seq_along(expr))
        expr[[i]] <- dummy_expr_processing(expr = expr[[i]])
}
dummy_pairlist_processing(f[[2]])
```

but that doesn't change anything.

I can also explicitly check if `expr` is missing

```
dummy_expr_processing <- function(expr) {
    if (missing(expr)) return()
    attr(expr, "foo") <- "bar"
    expr
}
```

This will work if I call `dummy_expr_processing` without an argument but *not* if I call it with a "missing" expression. Then it is not considered missing by the `missing()` function but it certainly *is* considered missing by `attr`.

I can get around *that* by exploiting that missing data is represented as an empty symbol, so I can do this:

```
dummy_expr_processing <- function(expr) {
    if (as.character(expr) == "") return()
    attr(expr, "foo") <- "bar"
    expr
}
dummy_pairlist_processing <- function(expr) {
    for (i in seq_along(expr))
        dummy_expr_processing(expr[[i]])
}
dummy_pairlist_processing(f[[2]])
```

and that will work, but notice that I no longer update `expr[[i]]` in dummy_pairlist_processing`. I cannot do that if I let`dummy_expr_processing`return`NULL`.

My questions now are:

1. Is `as.character(expr) == ""` the only way I can test if a variable holds an empty expression, or are there better ways?
2. Is there anyway I can also *return* the missing expression? Especially nice if I can return it *and* set an attribute on the returned object.

Comment: `if (as.character(expr) == "") return(expr)`

Comment: I'm absolutely convinced that I tried that and got an error when giving `return` `expr`, but right now it looks like it is working. I still can't set an attribute on the empty expression, though, but I can probably work around that.